# How do I manage multiple API Key files for local and production?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, vercel

I'm using React hosted on Vercel to build my website. I have a set of API keys for Stripe and Firebase integrated with my web application. There are two sets - development and production. Here's the config file I have set below:

```
// key.js - figure out what set of credentials to use based on the environment
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    };
    module.exports = firebaseConfig
} else {
    // we are in development - return the dev set of keys
    module.exports = require('./firebase.dev.js')      
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I run **npm run build** locally

> ...  code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',

I believe the source is coming from one of the firebase function calls that use an API key specified in this file. When running the build, instead of using the key specified in the **require('./firebase.dev.js')**, it's using the apiKey specified by the environment parameter **process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY**, which is not available until the build has access to the environment variables in the Vercel.

How do I set up the config file such that, when I run npm run build, it knows that it should build using the local keys?

Comment: Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running. Source : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: from which file are you loading your env variables?